# How to fail dependent tests if one test is failed in XCUITest?

Tags: xcuitest

I want to force fail my test if one of my dependent test fails in XCUITest

Ex: func testA() {
}

func testB()

if my func testA() fails then func testB() should also fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCUITest does not support dependencies between test cases. We can use the below workaround to overcome that.

```
class TestClass: XCTestCase {
    static var isTestAPassed = true

    override func setUp() {
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        if testRun?.test.name == "testA" {
            TestClass.isTestAPassed = testRun?.hasSucceeded
        }
    }

    func testA() {
    }

    func testB() {
        XCTAssertTrue(TestClass.isTestAPassed) 
    }
}
```